# SMO - SQL Server Job Enable/Disable icon does not refresh after an update

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, smo

In the following picture there is a small red spot at the icon for the job Test1Job indicating that this job is disabled. But the following code does not refresh the job icon. I have to go the the SQL Server Agent and manually refresh the job to see the change in the icon (enable to disable or vice versa). The code works in that it does disable/enable the job based on the value of `jb.IsEnabled` I set:

```
Job jb = srv.JobServer.Jobs["Test1Job"];
jb.IsEnabled = false;
jb.Alter();
jb.Refresh();
```

[image]

Comment: This is more of a question about SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and whether it's possible for the Object Explorer to auto-refresh. It appears currently not, out-of-the-box at least.

Answer (score 0):

A Boolean value that specifies whether the job is enabled or not.If True, the job is enabled. If False (default), the job is not enabled.

```
Server srv = new Server("(local)");
Job jb = new Job(srv.JobServer, "Test Job");
jb.IsEnabled = true;
```

Setting the IsEnabled property of a Job object to False disables a Microsoft SQL Server Agent job. A disabled job does not run.

Comment: You probably misread my question. As stated in the last line of my post, my code works fine and it does enable or disable the job based on the the value I set for `jb.IsEnabled`. The issue is that the red spot at the icon does not refresh itself to display the Enable or Disable status. I've to go to SQL Server Agent to manually refresh the icon.